# Numpy replace matrix elementwise with another matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have an n * x numpy matrix, which could look like this:

```
a = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
```

and I have another n * n numpy matrix, which look like this:

```
b = np.array([[2, 2], [2, 2]])
```

I would like to replace zero elements of `a` with the corresponding element of `b` so I would get:

```
[[1, 2],
 [2, 1]]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a boolean mask:

```
mask = (a == 0)
a[mask] = b[mask]
```

This is efficient if you want to update the original array `a` since it only assigns to the zero elements, not the whole array.

Comment: I think `numpy.where` is the elegant way to do it

Comment: @ansev The question asked for replacing elements in an array, not computing a new array. Using `numpy.where` for that task is going to be inefficient if only a few number of elements are zero as it needs to assign the whole array back to `a`.

Comment: On a test (1000,1000) array, this answer is 3-4x faster than the `where`.  `np.copyto` with a `where` parameter is a bit faster than this, `np.copyto(a, b, where=a==0) `.  Exact time advantages may very with the proportion of 0s in `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj This makes sense since the masking solution needs to loop over the mask twice and creates a temporary object for the r.h.s while `np.copyto` can loop all parts together and doesn't need a temporary array. Very good!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.where`:

```
np.where(a!=0, a, b)

array([[1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
​
```